# How to store different entire columns in Variable?

Tags: vba, excel, compiler-errors

Here's what i have so far :

```
    Set cell = Cells.Find(What:="ABC", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    Set cell2 = Cells.Find(What:="DEF", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    Set cell3 = Cells.Find(What:="GHI", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)


i = Union(cell.EntireColumn, cell2.EntireColumn, cell3.EntireColumn).Value

Do Until i = ""
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Selection.Cells(1, 1), _
DataType:=xlDelimited, _
TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
Tab:=True, _
Semicolon:=False, _
Comma:=False, _
Space:=False, _
Other:=False, _
FieldInfo:=Array(1, 1), _
TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
Loop
```

Here what i am trying to do is, i want to store the columns and then i want to do the formatting until set columns completed.
But i am getting error on below line as Run-time error '13': Type mismatch.

```
i = Union(cell.EntireColumn, cell2.EntireColumn, cell3.EntireColumn).Value
```

Please help me.

Comment: that will return an array

Comment: @Nathan_Sav Thanks but i tried with Array also [ xx = Array(cell.EntireColumn, cell2.EntireColumn, cell3.EntireColumn) ] but getting same error on next step i.e. ` Do Until xx ="" `

Comment: look at how to access an array, which you can do like that.  you'll need `x(x,y,z)` where x,y,z are looped based on it's dimensions. `ubound` `lbound` will be a start in determining dimensions.

Comment: hmm actually i don't know how to do that...Okay i will do R&D

Comment: This will help you get to grips with arrays, they can be tricky to understand, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/locals-window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i able to solve the issue with below code...

```
    Set cell = Cells.Find(What:="ABC", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    Set cell2 = Cells.Find(What:="DEF", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    Set cell3 = Cells.Find(What:="GHI", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

   x = Array(cell.Column, cell2.Column, cell3.Column)


   For Each item In x
      Cells(1, item).Select
      Selection.EntireColumn.Select

        Selection.EntireColumn.Select
        Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Selection.Cells(1, 1), _
        DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
        ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
        Tab:=True, _
        Semicolon:=False, _
        Comma:=False, _
        Space:=False, _
        Other:=False, _
        FieldInfo:=Array(1, 1), _
        TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
   Selection.NumberFormat = 0
   Next
```

actually the problem was when i was defining the array of columns, i observed that `cell, cell2, cell3` value was wrong, it was capturing the text instead of column number....
the problem was with below
Before

```
x = Array(cell.EntireColumn, cell2.EntireColumn, cell3.EntireColumn)
```

After

```
x = Array(cell.Column, cell2.Column, cell3.Column)
```

thanks all of your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

As Nathan already stated current line returns an array of values.

```
i = Union(cell.EntireColumn, cell2.EntireColumn, cell3.EntireColumn).Value
```

You tryed to counter it with creating **3**-dimensional array (am I guessing right?).

```
xx = Array(cell.EntireColumn, cell2.EntireColumn, cell3.EntireColumn)
```

Having 3 separate columns does not define a **3**-dimensional array. You united 3 columns and it resulted in a table which means it is still a **2**-dimensional array (any construct as x=range(****).value returns a **2**-dimensional array even if range you specified consists of one column).
What you have to do is to loop through this new **2**-dimensional array and check if it is empty.

P.S. You might want to format union of ranges with calculated number of rows (find last non-empty cell in each column) at once instead of looping through each cell in **2**-dimensional array.